# Ubuntu automatically clean zombie and sleeping process

Tags: python3, multi-core, zombie

Is there a way how I can cleanup zombie process automatically? How can I clean up the zombie and sleeping process automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by clean up? Literally almost all processes are either sleeping or zombie processes, since few are currently CPU-bound.

Comment: If you are developing a python application that forks and you see zombies it means there is an error in your program: the father should wait for each child end and acknowledge (that is get their return id) so that they cease to be zombies...